# Oracle equivalent ROWNUM for SQL-Server 2005?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

In Oracle PL/SQL I was used to write:

```
SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE WHERE ROWNUM <= 100;
```

in order to fetch only the first 100 records of the table named MY_TABLE.

What could be the equivalent SELECT statement in SQL SERVER?

Comment: As ordered by what? There is no "natural" ordering of rows.

Comment: I have just corrected the title of the question by adding '2005'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT TOP 100 * FROM TABLE
```

You can also filter rows by using where class

```
SELECT TOP 100 * FROM YOURTABLE WHERE YOURCONDITION
```

Comment: OK, but I need only a sample of the records, because they are over 5 million records.

Comment: @UltraCommit - if you just want a *sample*, why not specify a [`TABLESAMPLE` clause](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177634(v=sql.90))? Expressing your *intent* as clearly as possible is usually a good thing to do.

Comment: Great comment, Damien_The_Unbeliever.  I have just tried with: select * from my_secret_table tablesample (0.01 percent);

Answer (score 3):

In SQL-Server You can Use [TOP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189463.aspx) to select the no. of rows.

```
SELECT TOP 100 * FROM MY_TABLE
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select top 100 * from tbl
```

column name is required or use *

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT TOP 100 * FROM MY_TABLE
```

Sorry if I misunderstood.

**Edit:** Must be faster

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server 2012, you can use `OFFSET` and `FETCH` to determine which rows to return. They're documented under [`ORDER BY`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188385.aspx); This makes sense since asking for 100 rows, when tables are *by definition* unordered, gives unpredictable results.

Similarly, if you use other's answers, re: `TOP`, you should *also* have an `ORDER BY` clause, or else it's **not defined** which rows will be returned.