# Need to convert Oracle to Mssql

Tags: sql-server, oracle, migration, rownum

```
SELECT COLUMN FROM TABLE WHERE ACTION='ABC' AND ROWNUM<=1;
```

I have a doubt in mssql. I need to migrate the above oracle query into mssql. I'm struggling with `ROWNUM`.

Comment: [Similar name, different syntax](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx). But why bother with `ROWNUM <= 1` instead of `SELECT TOP X`?

Comment: Refer this :  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11226153/oracle-equivalent-rownum-for-sql-server-2005

Comment: You've modified the question? You should post a new question instead of editing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT TOP 1 COLUMN 
FROM TABLE 
WHERE ACTION='ABC'
```

You may need to use `Order By` too, which is...

```
SELECT TOP 1 COLUMN 
FROM TABLE 
WHERE ACTION='ABC' 
Order by columnnane asc/desc
```

*note*: if you don't specify the direction (`ASC` / `DESC`) after the Order By, the default is ASC.

Comment: Couldn't format earlier as I was on my mobile device :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT Top 10 * FROM TABLE WHERE ACTION='ABC'
```